VMware workstation kills Ubuntu host - rcu_preempt
I am wondering if someone else experienced this problem.
My host is a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 with Ubuntu 24.04 and VMware workstation 17.6 installed. When starting a VM my host loses immediately its network connectivity and also the VMs do not have network. Trying to execute a sudo command from shell just freezes the shell. Trying to reboot the machine hangs and after a while I get rcu_preempt messages.
The closed I found on the internet is: this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=290839
They are talking about Kernel issues with 6.8, but which have been solved with Kernel 6.8.4. As far as I understand, Ubuntu 24.04 uses its own Kernel build and also updating to Kernel 6.9 is not planed ?!? (https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle).
Because I am not really a Linux expert I would like to know if you have similar issues with VMware on Ubuntu 24.04. I also don't like the idea adding a different repro to upgrade the Kernel?!?!
Thanks
Stephan
Edit:
I followed this guide https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-9-on-ubuntu-24-04-lts-heres-how to also install kernel 6.8.12 and Vmware started to work again. However, afterwards I was not able to launch Firefox snap snymore and on the reboot got some systemd-hostname blocked messages.

Have you asked this on a VMware support forum?

I had the same problem after upgrading from vmware 17.5.2 to 17.6 on an HP book with ubuntu 24.04.
I solved it reinstalling 17.5.2 (with vmon vnet patch for kernel 6.9).

Hi Walter,
so you also do not use the Ubuntu default kernel? Maybe I should switch to kvm qemu

I am using default kernel.
The patch comes from
https://github.com/nan0desu/vmware-host-modules/tree/tmp/workstation-17.5.2-k6.9. It is tagged for kernel 6.9 but it works also with 6.8 (the default kernel of Ubuntu 24.01).

You need to patch the vmware workstation host modules. The Patch https://github.com/bytium/vm-host-modules from Bytium worked for me on ubuntu 24.04. Bytium also published instruction to install the patch can be found at https://bytium.com/vmware-workstation-host-module-patch-for-debian-and-ubuntu/

I didn't try it but I don't think that bytium patch can fix this problem. When I installed vmware 17.6 original (not patched) vmmon and vmnet modules compiled without errors.
The problem arose after a reboot. All the system was unresponsive. It was not possible even to open a console. I had to boot in safe mode (no GUI) to uninstall vmware 17.6.
